# Method that checks if user has a plan and then adds another plan

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a model method that does this:

- Checks if the user has `plan_one`. If so, then deactivate `plan_one`.
- Checks if the user has `plan_two`. If not, then add `plan_two` to the user.

Can I do this all in a single method, or do I need to set up a second method and then call it in the first method?

```
def have_plan_one?
  # function that checks if user has a plan_one
  sub.plans.active.where(name: plan_one).any?

  # if user has plan 1, deactivate it
  if sub.have_plan_one?
    sub.plans.where(name: plan_one).deactivate
  end

  # if user doesn't have plan 2, add it
  if sub.have_plan_two? == false
    sub.plans.where(name: plan_two).add
  end
end

def have_plan_two?
  # function that checks if user has a plan_two
  sub.plans.active.where(name: plan_two).any?
end
```

Comment: What is the relation between `sub.plans` and `sub.plan`?

Comment: typo! edited them all as `plans`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoupling your code into different methods is mostly about conceptual approaches rather then real technical difference. According to Sandy Metz rules(https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers) I would suggest you to keep your methods up to 5 lines of code. I would go with something like this:

```
def switch_plans
  deactivate_plan_one
  activate_plan_two
end

def deactivate_plan_one
  sub.plans.active.where(name: plan_one).first.try(:deactivate)
end

def activate_plan_two
  sub.plan.where(name: plan_two).add if sub.have_plan_two? == false
end
```

You can make `switch_plans` just to contain 2 rows, that I wrote in separate methods, but I think this is something that definitely would be reused in other places, so I would keep it as I wrote.

Also, I want to mention, that logic inside methods still don't look good and you can think about some ways to make it better

Comment: Your answer is awesome, sir! :)